# Flutter iOS In-app purchase issue (storekit_duplicate_product_object)

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an app for iOS. Normally I have one more app and in-app purchases are also working fine. Since my other application is similar, I use exactly the same codes and it should work under normal conditions, but I think there may be such a problem because I published the application from scratch and no product was approved. (Note: It works flawlessly on Android) The error I got is as follows.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(storekit_duplicate_product_object, There is a pending transaction for the same product identifier. Please either wait for it to be finished or finish it manuelly usingcompletePurchase to avoid edge cases., {applicationUsername: null, requestData: null, quantity: 1, productIdentifier: premium, simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox: null}) #0
```

I am using the same version in_app_purchase class in both my apps. Do you think the problem is application-based or is there something I need to do on Apple's side?